# break data into each level and apply function to it

Tags: r, split, dataframe, plyr, apply

I have following dataset:

```
name1 <- c("P1", "P2", "IndA", "IndB", "IndC", "IndD", "IndE", "IndF", "IndG")
name2 <- c("P1", "P2", "IndH", "IndI", "IndJ", "IndK")
name3 <- c("P1", "P2", "IndL", "IndM", "IndN")
name <- c(name1, name2, name3)

A <- c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3,2,1 )
B <- c(2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2,2, 1, 2, 1 )
family  = c(rep(1, length (name1)), rep(2, length (name2)), rep(3, length (name3)))
mydf <- data.frame (family, name, A, B)
```

The following is process I want to apply each level of family variable:

```
dum.match<-rbind(expand.grid(c(mydf[1,3:4]),c(mydf[2,3:4])),
        expand.grid(c(mydf[2,3:4]),  c(mydf  [1,3:4])))
    newmydf<-cbind(mydf, correct = paste(mydf$A,mydf$B)%in%paste(dum.match$Var1,
        dum.match$Var2))
```

So I generated a function:

```
err.chk <- function (x) {
    dum.match<-rbind(expand.grid(c(x[1,3:4]),c(x[2,3:4])),
     expand.grid(c(x[2,3:4]),c(x[1,3:4])))
    newmydf<-cbind(x, correct = paste(x$A,mydf$B)%in%paste(dum.match$Var1,
     dum.match$Var2))
    return (newmydf)
    }
```

Now I want to create seperate 3 dataset for each level of family and apply the above function and combine the results into above dataframe with additional column correct. How can I do it ? I tried following (and results are awaful !)

```
 require(plyr) 
 aaply(mydf, 1, err.chk)
```

**Edit:**

Expected output:

```
family name A B  correct 
1       1   P1 1 2  FALSE
2       1   P2 3 4  FALSE
3       1 IndA 1 3  TRUE
4       1 IndB 2 4  TRUE
5       1 IndC 2 2  FALSE
6       1 IndD 5 2  FALSE
7       1 IndE 5 6  FALSE
8       1 IndF 1 2  FALSE
9       1 IndG 4 2  TRUE

10      2   P1 1 1  FALSE
11      2   P2 3 4  FALSE
12      2 IndH 3 3  FALSE
13      2 IndI 1 1  FALSE
14      2 IndJ 4 1  TRUE
15      2 IndK 3 5  FALSE 


16      3   P1 1 2  TRUE
17      3   P2 1 2  TRUE
18      3 IndL 3 1  FALSE
19      3 IndM 2 2  TRUE
20      3 IndN 1 1  TRUE
```

Just for family = 3 (similaly for other datasets)

```
    # just data for family 3
    name <- c("P1", "P2", "IndL", "IndM", "IndN")
    A <- c(1, 1, 3,2,1 )
    B <- c(2,2, 1, 2, 1)
    mydf <- data.frame (name, A, B)
    err.chk(fam3)

   name A B correct
16   P1 1 2    TRUE
17   P2 1 2    TRUE
18 IndL 3 1   FALSE
19 IndM 2 2    TRUE
20 IndN 1 1    TRUE
```

Comment: If you run the code you give in the first block before the function, its output does not match your expected output.  Row 4 is `FALSE` if you use only df[df$family==1,] in all of your calls to `mydf`.  Try working with a subset of your data (i.e. only one family) until you get your function working as you expect it to.  Then `ddply` is your answer.

Comment: @sorry justin, mybad ...I wrong indices 2:3 should be replaced by 3:4, I did not notice that family column is added ...now results are good and accepted your answer

Comment: no worries.  You can always avoid the hard coded column indicies buy using names.  `expand.grid(x[1, c('A', 'B')], x[2, c('A', 'B')])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to follow exactly what you're doing, but with `plyr` you want to use a `**ply` function that accepts the data type you're giving it and returns the data type your function returns.  In this case, `ddply` looks like the right choice.

If you fix your function in the 3rd line you have a `mydf$B` which should be `x$B`:

```
err.chk <- function (x) {
  dum.match <- rbind(expand.grid(c(x[1, 2:3]), c(x[2, 2:3])),
                     expand.grid(c(x[2, 2:3]), c(x[1, 2:3])))
  newmydf <- cbind(x, correct = paste(x$A, x$B) %in% paste(dum.match$Var1, dum.match$Var2))

  return (newmydf)
}
```

Calling it using `ddply` gives a reasonable looking result.

```
> ddply(mydf, .(family), err.chk)
   family name A B correct
1       1   P1 1 2   FALSE
2       1   P2 3 4   FALSE
3       1 IndA 1 3    TRUE
4       1 IndB 2 4    TRUE
5       1 IndC 2 2   FALSE
6       1 IndD 5 2   FALSE
7       1 IndE 5 6   FALSE
8       1 IndF 1 2   FALSE
9       1 IndG 4 2    TRUE
10      2   P1 1 1   FALSE
11      2   P2 3 4   FALSE
12      2 IndH 3 3   FALSE
13      2 IndI 1 1   FALSE
14      2 IndJ 4 1    TRUE
15      2 IndK 3 5   FALSE
16      3   P1 1 2    TRUE
17      3   P2 1 2    TRUE
18      3 IndL 3 1   FALSE
19      3 IndM 2 2    TRUE
20      3 IndN 1 1    TRUE
```

Comment: sorry mybad ...I wrong indices 2:3 should be replaced by 3:4, I did not notice that family column is added ...now results are good and accepted your answer